# Run multiple $.get() from single change event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking for the correct way to run more than 1 $.get() event from a single change event. The code I have posted only returns the first call to loadboxDstrsubcat.php?dstrdept.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. I know there is the **.when** option, but I am still quite green to ajax so any help would be mist welcome. Thanks

```
$(function() {

$("#dstr_dept").chosen({
      width: "260px",
      placeholder_text_single: "Select Some Options"
    }).change(function() {

    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('loadboxDstrsubcat.php?dstrdept=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#box_dstr").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#box_dstr").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
  });

  $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('loadboxAdrDstrsubcat.php?dstraddr=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#dstr_address").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#dstr_address").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: The point is that you need to call your second get inside the success of first get!

Comment: Could you expand on that please Ramzan by way of an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you try to call it within the first $.get, try:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dstr_dept").chosen({
        width: "260px",
        placeholder_text_single: "Select Some Options"
    }).change(function () {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
        $.get('loadboxDstrsubcat.php?dstrdept=' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $("#box_dstr").trigger("chosen:updated");
            });
            $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
            $.get('loadboxAdrDstrsubcat.php?dstraddr=' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
                $("#dstr_address").html(data);
                $('#loader').slideUp(200, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    $("#dstr_address").trigger("chosen:updated");
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Still only seeing the first $.get() Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way

```
$(function() {

$("#dstr_dept").chosen({
      width: "260px",
      placeholder_text_single: "Select Some Options"
    }).change(function() {

    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('loadboxDstrsubcat.php?dstrdept=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#box_dstr").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#box_dstr").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    }).done(function( data ) {

       //call second get here
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /</div>');
    $.get('loadboxAdrDstrsubcat.php?dstraddr=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#dstr_address").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#dstr_address").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
   });       

    });
  });


});
```

Comment: That gives me 'TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined' error. Thanks

Comment: There is no line number Ramzan. Just a link to the jquery.js that triggered the error. Thanks